# How to show the keyboard for edittext in overlay?

Tags: java, android, overlay, android-softkeyboard

I have an overlay and a text field in it. But when I want to enter text in the field, the virtual keyboard is not displayed.

I have tried all the flags (`FLAG_LOCAL_FOCUS_MODE`, `FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM`, `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`), but it did not bring any result.

Here is my code:

```java
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        width - 100,
        height - 100,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
        //WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
        //WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LOCAL_FOCUS_MODE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
params.x = 50;
params.y = 50;

ConstraintLayout rootView = (ConstraintLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.overlay_layout, null);
windowManager.addView(rootView, params);
```

How to fix it?

Comment: use this editText.requestFocus();

Comment: Hi, I just encountered this issue. Were you able to resolve it? @karlson

Comment: @QasimMalik It was a long time ago, so I don't remember what exactly worked for me. But maybe it will help you: `code`WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        width - 100, 
        height - 100,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

Comment: @karlson Thanks for your response, I was able to resolve the issue after studying this  https://github.com/atifmahmood29/overlays-floating-window-like-facebook-messenger/blob/master/app/src/main/java/innovativepocket/com/systemalertwindow/FloatingWindow.java